# Adjusting a footer image so that it's offset by 10pixels?

Tags: html, css

My webpage has a static header and footer and for my top logo/image the image overhangs by 10pixels which is what I want it to do, but my bottom image overhangs off the end of the screen, I want it to be a minus offset so that the top of the image starts 10 pixels higher than the footer...

If you check the image [image] You can see what it currently looks like (Green = Correct, Red = Incorrect)

If you check the image [image] You can see this is what it is supposed to look like, with the image overhanging on both static bars.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ag8jV/)

The part of the css that I have been fiddling with to try and it it working is:

```
#footer_container {
    background: #262A2D url('gradhead.png') repeat-x;
    border: 0px solid #666;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 80px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ECECEC;
}

#footer .footimage {
}
```

If I throw in a `top: -10px;` in the `#footer` css everything offsets which is isn't quite what I'm looking for it fixes the main image but everything else moves up...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your CSS declarations:

```
#footer .footimage {
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ag8jV/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could easily just move the position of the image in the footer up 10px this works since you know the offset that you need.

```
#footer .headimager {
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
}
```

Here's a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/dPLWE/

Answer (score 0):

Add to your bottom img

```
{position: absolute; bottom: 0;}
```

but then you have to align it with JS if you want it to align to the screen.